# Renaming temporary files in Python

Tags: python, temporary-files

I want to do the following. Create a temporary file and work on it. If successful, rename it to a real file. If it fails, then delete the file.

I tried the following:

```py
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir=os.getcwd()) as f:
    f.write(b'foobar')
    f.delete = False
    f.flush()
    os.rename(f.name, 'foobar')
```

However, I still get an exception that the file does not exist when it tries to delete it. I might use a try-catch to ignore this error, but that would be ugly and might ignore other errors too. Or I could use `mkstemp()` and manage deletion myself, but that has a problem that it returns a file descriptor instead of a file object, and I couldn't find a way to create a file object from the file descriptor.

Is there any proper solution to the problem?

Comment: *"I still get an exception that the file does not exist when it tries to delete it*" Because you renamed it?

Comment: @DeepSpace: Yes. The question is how to avoid that.

Comment: @petersohn: Do you need Windows support?

Comment: You don't know about `os.fdopen`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `delete=False` during initialization, setting `f.delete = False` later is not working. I was able to rename it after writing with this code:

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir=os.getcwd(), delete=False) as f:
    f.write(b'foobar')
    f.flush()
    os.rename(f.name, 'foobar')
```

I went through the code of [Lib/tempfile.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9d3b6b2472f7c7ef841e652825de652bc8af85d7/Lib/tempfile.py) to confirm this behavior.

When you call `NamedTemporartyFile`, it initializes and returns an instance of `_TemporaryFileWrapper` class defined in the same file. Look at the `__init__()` of this class:

```
def __init__(self, file, name, delete=True):
        self.file = file
        self.name = name
        self.delete = delete
        self._closer = _TemporaryFileCloser(file, name, delete)
```

And here is the `__init__()` of `_TemporaryFileCloser` class:

```
def __init__(self, file, name, delete=True):
        self.file = file
        self.name = name
        self.delete = delete
```

When you exit from the with statement, during closing of the file, the `self.delete` attribute of `_TemporaryFileCloser` is checked. While when you do `f.delete = False`, you change the `self.delete` attribute of the `_TemporaryFileWrapper` class instead of the `_TemporaryFileCloser` class. Therefore, the closing behavior is not altered even if it looks like that on developer side. So you must pass `delete=False` during the initialization in the `with` statement like in my code example.

If you still want to modify the behavior, you can access `self._closer` attribute, it will be a little ugly however.

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir=os.getcwd()) as f:
    f.write(b'foobar')
    f.flush()
    f._closer.delete = False
    os.rename(f.name, 'foobar')
```

Btw, I performed this on Ubuntu WSL on Windows 10. I'm not sure which OS you are using, that might affect the behavior.

Comment: I passed `delete=True` at the beginning because I wanted it to delete the file in case of an error. But I guess I need to delete it manually instead.

Comment: Why to use `f.flush()` instead of `f.close()`? I used your example with `f.close()`, it works ok.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved with the [`NamedTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) class. Once closed, you can move it to the desired location/filename. You need to close the file before moving it to avoid the deletion error.

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import shutil

with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as tmp:
    tmp.write(b'hi')

# move file to target location/name
shutil.move(tmp.name, 'target')
```

Comment: I don’t think the documented Windows issue prevents this use from working on Windows – closing the file before moving it should only be required on Windows, even. Also, the key part here is `delete=False` (`NamedTemporaryFile` is already in the question).

Comment: I once tried to get this to work. Neither setting for delete would let me close the file (as that was required to be able to execute the file as otherwise one gets a busy file error) and have the file deleted when the with block exited.

Comment: @DanD. did you try the code above? It works for me. If the file is deleted when closed, th en it cannot be moved to a new location anymore.